# node 0.11.13 gives an error for generator syntax

Tags: node.js, generator, koa

Node version 0.11.13 gives out an error:

[image]

How it can be solved?

PS the code is a simple example:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run Node with the `--harmony` flag at the command line to enable features like generators that are part of Harmony.